# python web scraping: How to read Twitter Class Names or IDS or DIV.name......or whatever the identifier is

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, bots

**Hello everyone i had a problem with the below code that i created,**
**i cannot identify the class name or id or name of twitter page when i log into it and select those divs** 
**and then make like for all of them, and i put the the old class name which was tweet**

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 import time

 class TwitterBot:
   def __init__(self, username, password):
      self.username = username
      self.password = password
      self.bot = webdriver.Chrome()
   def login(self):
      bot = self.bot
      #bot.get("Url of twitter to /login/")
      time.sleep(2)

      email = bot.find_elements_by_name('session[username_or_email]')[1]
      password = bot.find_elements_by_name('session[password]')[1]

      email.clear()
      password.clear()
      email.send_keys(self.username)
      password.send_keys(self.password)
      password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
      time.sleep(1)
  def like_tweets(self,Hashtag):
      bot = self.bot
      bot.get('https://twitter.com/search?q='+ Hashtag +'&src=typd')
      time.sleep(1)
      for i in range(1,5):
        bot.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
        time.sleep(1)
        tweets = bot.find_elements_by_class_name("tweet")
        links  = [elem.get_attribute('data-permalink-path') for elem in tweets]
        for link in links:
            bot.get('https://twitter.com' + link)
            try:
                #print(links)
                bot.find_elements_by_class_name('HeartAnimation').click()
                time.sleep(10)
            except Exception as ex:
                time.sleep(60)



Omar = TwitterBot('My username', 'My Password')
Omar.login()
Omar.like_tweets('مرتضي منصور')
```

Comment: Change your password immediately and remember this for the future. I just copy and pasted your code, ran it, and it successfully logged in except for the security question challenge.

Comment: I am a bit confused. What specifically are you having trouble with this time?

Comment: After i login successfully (after your precious support) i need to detect(find all) all love\like buttons in tweets and then press(click) them all, but the problem is: i can`t identify them through their class name Id or any identifier, hope to get to my point and thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest twitter has somehow managed to prevent this type of selection by selenium. You can try with pyautogui. My suggestion would be to focus on twitter official API,as I also failed . Also this type of bot is a violation of twitter's terms. Cheers!

Comment: fat thanks Abudallh for your instance support, and Python auto gui working on it right now , السلام عليكم يا أخي

Comment: Peace be upon you too. If you really want to build something like this, you need to focus on total keyboard input automation (tab, shift+enter etc) . This does not ensure 100% accuracy. 
Keep in mind that this type of bot is not allowed by twitter. Twitter official API is easy to learn. Happy coding! Good luck!